# Why is Compose missing my app launcher icon?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've introduced Jetpack Compose into my project. But now my app's icon isn't found in the launcher. If I revert to run my legacy Activity then the launcher icon re-appears. Here's my `AndroidManifest` in case y'all see something that I don't.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.es0329.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.App.DayNight"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.ComposeActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.App.DayNight.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.flipper.android.diagnostics.FlipperDiagnosticActivity"
            android:exported="true" />

        <meta-data android:name="io.sentry.auto-init" android:value="false" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```